# Остановка проигрования музыки с использованием JLayer

Tags: swing, jlayer

По видеоуроку написал аудиоплеер с использованием JLayer трабл в том что открытие файла организировано через кнопку с FileChooser но после открития песни кнопки перестают нажыматься а кнопка закрития фрейма не реагирует баг или же есть лекарство? вот код кнопки открытия

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
               chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
     String file;
               file = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);


        Player playmp3 = new Player(fis);
        playmp3.play();
```

на второй кнопке просто System.exit(0);